# Can't run SCP - Containment Breach on mac with Wine

Tags: technical-issues, macos, emulation, wine, scp-containment-breach

I'm trying to run SCP - Containment Breach on mac with wine. My mac has very limited storage space, and as a result, I don't have enough space for boot camp.

Basically, I had a problem where when trying to load the game, at 45% loading, it would give me a memory access violation error. I looked around, and found a way to fix it. Now that's fixed, but now I'm presented with a new error. The game says 'cannot load fog.jpg', and won't load any further. Any help?